# My custom Docker image doesn't have networking

Tags: docker, networking

this one's a little bit odd but I may need some guidance on that.

I've created a custom image starting from `maven:3.6-jdk-8`, and the image seems to work just fine.

However, it's like there's no network in my container.

To see if it was an issue related to my machine, I did some tests with another container, and it works fine.

Here's a little bit of output:

(working 3rd-party tool)

```
docker run -it --net host nicolaka/netshoot
                    dP            dP                           dP
                    88            88                           88
88d888b. .d8888b. d8888P .d8888b. 88d888b. .d8888b. .d8888b. d8888P
88'  `88 88ooood8   88   Y8ooooo. 88'  `88 88'  `88 88'  `88   88
88    88 88.  ...   88         88 88    88 88.  .88 88.  .88   88
dP    dP `88888P'   dP   `88888P' dP    dP `88888P' `88888P'   dP

Welcome to Netshoot! (github.com/nicolaka/netshoot)
root @ /
 [1]   → curl www.google.com
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="it"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/lo... rest of google.com output
```

(my non-working image)

```
docker run -it myimage/myimage /bin/bash
root@eab59605cf95:/# curl www.google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com
```

Both containers have the very same contents in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and I really don't know what to look for to solve this issue.

EDIT: I forgot that using `ping` in both containers resolves the very same ip for `google.com`, which makes things weirder.

Comment: Have you attached a docker network to this docker image?

Comment: I didn't (and I can't because images are started by my Gitlab Runner) attach a network to neither the images, but one works and the other doesn't.